# google+ hangout OnAir button Html tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-hangouts

I got html button tags for normal hangouts but i didn't get any hangout button html tag for OnAir.
i am using the below tag, but i am unable to get onair button.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div class="g-hangout" data-render="createhangout" type="onair"></div>
```

Can anyone get me the exact html code for onair google+ hangout?

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div5"></div>
<script>
gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div5', {
  'topic': 'cats',
  'render': 'createhangout',
  'hangout_type': 'onair',
  'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
  'widget_size': 72
});
</script>
```

After refresh the page, I got blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check your browser console you might be getting

> Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

this error for sure which can sorted out if you add a script along with platform.js here's the script.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the Hang Out OnAir button you need to use the following code

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div5"></div>
```

please refer the jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/42/

Comment: Thanks , but i tried your code, you can get the edited of mine above. but after putting the same code and refresh my page, it got a blank page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" type="text/javascript"/>
    <div id="placeholder-div5"/>
    <script>
            gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div5', {
              'topic': 'cats',
              'render': 'createhangout',
              'hangout_type': 'onair',
              'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
              'widget_size': 72
        });
    </script>
```

or this :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div5"></div>
<script>
        window.onLoadCallback = function(){
        gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div5', {
          'topic': 'cats',
          'render': 'createhangout',
          'hangout_type': 'onair',
          'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
          'widget_size': 72
    });}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used normal and not onAir I dont think that creates any issue however after I added following code

```
 <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

like below

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="placeholder-div1"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div1', {
    'render': 'createhangout', 'topic':'just test topic!!!','invites':[ { 'id' : 'xxxx@gmail.com.com', 'invite_type' : 'EMAIL' },
    { 'id' : 'yyyy@gmail.com.com', 'invite_type' : 'EMAIL' }],
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }]
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also got blank page. when I looked by doing f12
I was getting following error

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

After doing lot of research found that this is because it is not running in any webserver hence I just started my python webserver from command prompt like below

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

it started webserver at port 80000 by giving following info on console

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

And then called hangout.html from same as below
http://localhost:8000/hangout.html
it showed me button at last.
Pasted this because I feel someone else could get help from this.